# Linking outlook PST file to dropbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, dropbox

I'm currently looking to link my email files to dropbox. My .pst is around 9 GB at the moment. Is dropbox going to sync the whole 9GB every time I receive an email or is dropbox only going to sync the changes to the file? I'd hate to see 9 GB go over the wire every time I receive a new email.

Thanks

Comment: I did not test this with a modern outlook, but with 2003 and older it will sync the whole .pst since the whole files changes if you access it. (And just starting outlook is enough to modify it, no need to add mail, delete mail or anything similar ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Dropbox's own website https://www.dropbox.com/help/8/en the answer is no. It will only upload those parts of the file which have changed, not the entire file each time.

That said, keep in mind that while Outlook is running it will lock the .pst file, and therefore during that time Dropbox will not backup the changes. If your machine is on all day but Outlook isn't then this might not be a problem, but if Outlook is open whenever your PC is online then it could mean that it's never able to upload those changes.